# How to make disable right click on selected row in TableView in java fx?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, right-click

I am creating TableView in JavaFX.By clicking the left mouse button, I choose a table row, the same occurs, when I click the right mouse button. I want to make right-click disable with no focus on the row.Also I tried:

> table.setSelectionModel(null);

How can I do this?

## class  TableViewer

```
public class TableViewer extends Application {
private TableView table = new TableView();
final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
        new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
        new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
        new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
        new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(450);
    stage.setHeight(500);

    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    table.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

    TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

    table.setItems(data);
    table.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
    });
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

## class  Person

```
public class Person {
private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
private final SimpleStringProperty email;

public Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
    this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
    this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
    this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName.get();
}

public void setFirstName(String fName) {
    firstName.set(fName);
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName.get();
}

public void setLastName(String fName) {
    lastName.set(fName);
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email.get();
}

public void setEmail(String fName) {
    email.set(fName);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            e.consume();
        }
    });
    return row ;
});
```

Note: you should properly type your table and columns, instead of using raw types. I.e. you need to replace

```
private TableView table = new TableView();
```

with

```
private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
```

and

```
TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
```

with

```
TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
```

etc..

Comment: Thanks for your answer and especially for the Note.I tried your variant,but it doesn't work.

Comment: I mean when I click the right mouse button, there are still the focus on the row. So my problem isn't solved.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to happen? I assumed you meant that you didn't want a right-click to change the selection. You want the right-click to clear the selection? What's the exact functionality you need?

Comment: I want while I click the right mouse button nothing happens, no selection, no focus on the row.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm seeing with my code... Right-click makes no change to the selection (or focus).

Comment: I tried again  and it works, but only for left click. I dont know what is the problem for right click.

'    table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    e.consume();
                }
            });
            return row;
        });'

Comment: Maybe your mouse buttons are set up in a non-standard way somehow? What if you do `if (e.getButton() != MouseButton.PRIMARY)`?

Comment: if I use
 `if (e.getButton() != MouseButton.PRIMARY)`
 I have result when nothing happens,but for left click not right .

Comment: Windows, for example, has in the Control Panel -> Mouse -> Buttons and option "Switch primary and secondary buttons". It seems you have it set, or the equivalent in whatever operating system you happen to be using.